# Google scripts if statement inside class

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So what I'm trying to do is everytime a form is submitted it will run some code which will check if a certain cell = fine. If it is fineI want it to create that choice but if it is not fine then I want it to not create the choice. This is my current code but I am unable to put an if statement inside the .setChoices

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QARjdbtFpERRkP7Mw7Ud56plOygMzQawjQbXsbf9Hgw");
  var mh1 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C4");
  var mh2 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C5");
  var hellcat1 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C6");
  var hellcat2 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C7");
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var item = form.addListItem();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var deleteold = items[2];
  form.deleteItem(deleteold);
  Utilities.sleep(200);
  item.setTitle('Helicopters')
     .setRequired(true)
     .setChoices([
           item.createChoice('MH-9 #1'),
           item.createChoice('MH-9 #2'),
           item.createChoice('Hellcat #1'),
           item.createChoice('Hellcat #2')
     ])
  var items = form.getItems();
  var movenew = items[5];
  form.moveItem(movenew, 2)
```

So what I want would be something like this

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QARjdbtFpERRkP7Mw7Ud56plOygMzQawjQbXsbf9Hgw");
  var mh1 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C4");
  var mh2 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C5");
  var hellcat1 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C6");
  var hellcat2 = ss.getRange ("Helicopter Status!C7");
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var item = form.addListItem();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var deleteold = items[2];
  form.deleteItem(deleteold);
  Utilities.sleep(200);
  item.setTitle('Helicopters')
     .setRequired(true)
     .setChoices([
           if(mh1 == 'Fine'){
           item.createChoice('MH-9 #1'),
           }
           item.createChoice('MH-9 #2'),
           item.createChoice('Hellcat #1'),
           item.createChoice('Hellcat #2')
     ])
  var items = form.getItems();
  var movenew = items[5];
  form.moveItem(movenew, 2)
```

Comment: Whoops, fixed it should've been if it's fine i want it to create not if it's destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you do not need to carry out your if statement within choices. Into setChoices you are passing an array []; Why not build that array outside of your setChoices - assign it to a variable then pass the variable in.

```
   var  choices =  []

   if(mh1 === 'Fine'){
       Logger.log('Hit if')
       choices.push(item.createChoice('MH-9 #1'));
       }
       choices.push(item.createChoice('MH-9 #2'))
       choices.push(item.createChoice('Hellcat #1'))
       choices.push(item.createChoice('Hellcat #2'))

    item.setTitle('Helicopters').setRequired(true).setChoices(choices)
```

Comment: The issue which I'm having now is that even though cell C4 has Fine in it, it won't actually put the choice MH-9 in the form

Comment: I updated the code a little. You should check in the view - logs if the if statement is being hit.

Comment: Fixed it using .getValues(). Thanks for the answer!